# Instantiate node module differently per (web) user

Tags: node.js

I was wondering what the best practice is for the following scenario:

I am planning to use an npm module for a web servie, where the user enters a access and secret key. Then a module is used which is instantiated like this:

```
var module = require('module')('ACCESS_KEY','SECRET_KEY');
```

Each user of course has a different access and secret key. The module exposes several functions which I want to use with the user's access and secret key on his behalf.

Now my question is, how I can 'require' that module with the keys from the database for each user, not just for the whole application with a single static pair. I am on node 8 and using ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial detail here is that this:

```
var module = require('module')('ACCESS_KEY','SECRET_KEY');
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
var moduleFunc = require('module');
var module = moduleFunc('ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY');
```

In other words, `'module'` exports a function, and you're calling that function with two arguments (`'ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY'`) and assigning the result to `module`.

That means you can instead `require('module')` at the top of your file and then use the function it gives you as many times as you want later on, with different arguments.

For example:

```
const someApi = require('some-api');

// ...later...

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const { ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY } = getUserKeys(req);

  const apiClient = someApi(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks!